# How do I add a series to a column chart at a specific index

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to set the position columns when adding a new series?

An example of what I would like to do with non-functional code at the end after adding a new series:

```
$(function () {
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [32.4, 33.2]
    }]
});

chart.addSeries( {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8]
    })

chart.series[0].index = 2;
chart.series[1].index = 3;
chart.series[2].index = 1;
chart.redraw();

});
```

Link to my a jsFiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/cug79br2/1/

In my case do not have all the series when I created the chart so I need to rearrange them after I have loaded the additional dataset. In this example I want to add the last series at index 1 and move the existing columns one notch to the right.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some pre-consideration work on your queries, then create logic to reorder before you add.  then the problem becomes colors, you want to keep the same color for each series otherwise people get confused. You can do that upfront as well. then get into the chart building (with much more simplified code structure). Unfortunately out of all of my charts The one that meets this criteria doesn't do this (I let the chips fall where they may...no reorder). So that is my two-cents hopefully someone else looking can help you with a specific example.

Comment: It is this logic to reorder before I add that eludes me :( How would pre-concideration help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I could find is to remove all series, sort them and add them again. In this case its helpful (maby necessary) to keep the data outside the Highcharts object. In my case an array named series_data.

```
$(function () {
var chart, series_data;
 series_data = [
    {
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [32.4, 33.2]
    }
];

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: series_data
});

while(chart.series.length){
    chart.series[0].remove();
}

series_data.push( {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8]
    }
);

_.each(_.sortBy(series_data, 'data.0').reverse(), function(series, i){
  series.index = i;

  // To keep animations pretty and the last added to animate, do tno add it in the loop but later.
  if(series.name === 'New York'){
    return;
  }

    chart.addSeries(series, true, false);
})

chart.addSeries(series_data[2], true, false);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cug79br2/23/

When adding the items again after they have been removed I ignore the 'New York' series and add it later but set the index on it so that the the newest series will be animated.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5],
            index: 4
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [32.4, 33.2],
            index: 3
        }]
    });

    chart.addSeries( {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8],
            index: 2
        })
         chart.addSeries( {
            name: 'New York1',
            data: [83.6, 78.8],
            index: 1
        })
```

Comment: In my case I can not set the indexes on the first two series since I do not have the next two, the series added later needs to be able to go anywhere in-between or before based on their (on load unknown) values.